# Cannot execute LibreOffice macro on Docker Linux

Tags: linux, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice

I want to execute a macro file on Linux created by Docker with the following docker file.

```
from ubuntu:22.04
run apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
  default-jre \
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-java-common \
  git \ 
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

run libreoffice --headless --terminate_after_init
```

And I want to run following command to apply macro on a xlsx file.
While similar code worked in Windows, it does not work in docker.
The shell just pauses and does nothing.

```shell
cp ./Module1.xba ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/Standard/
soffice --nolockcheck --nologo --headless --norestore --language=ja --nofirststartwizard  ./docs/test.xlsx "macro:///Standard.Module1.Main?language=Basic&location=application"
```

Module1.xba

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE script:module PUBLIC "-//OpenOffice.org//DTD OfficeDocument 1.0//EN" "module.dtd">
<!--
 * This file is part of the LibreOffice project.
 *
 * This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
 * License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
 * file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
 *
 * This file incorporates work covered by the following license notice:
 *
 *   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *   contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed
 *   with this work for additional information regarding copyright
 *   ownership. The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache
 *   License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
 *   except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 *   the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 .
-->
<script:module xmlns:script="http://openoffice.org/2000/script" script:name="Module1" script:language="StarBasic">REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Sub Main
  ThisComponent.calculateAll()
  ThisComponent.store()
  ThisComponent.close(True)
  StarDesktop.terminate()
End Sub


</script:module>
```

So, do I need to install additional packages or configure?

Comment: I didn't find a good docker answer on the SE network, but the poster at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244677/how-do-i-run-a-libreoffice-macro-from-the-command-line-without-gui suggests to run `soffice &` first. Also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73106306/run-libreoffice-macro-on-docker-container it is suggested to check macro security settings. One more link to check, although it's not about docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101855/libreoffice-headless-refuses-to-convert-unless-root-wont-work-from-php-scrip.

Comment: Thanks, @JimK I found the solution by changing LibreOffice setting file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the default macro security. And the general LibreOffice setting is in `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/Standard/registrymodifications.xcu` in Linux.
So, I pasted the following code to the setting file.

```yml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oor:items xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Setup/L10N"><prop oor:name="ooLocale" oor:op="fuse"><value>en-US</value></prop></item>
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Setup/Office"><prop oor:name="ooSetupInstCompleted" oor:op="fuse"><value>true</value></prop></item>
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/Security/Scripting"><prop oor:name="MacroSecurityLevel" oor:op="fuse"><value>0</value></prop></item>
</oor:items>
```